# проблема с подключением шрифта в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

столкнулся с тяжёлой проблемой,пытаюсь подключить шрит в pygame(python) но сталкиваюсь с различными проблемами
когда пишу так:

```
font_name = pygame.font.Font(path.join(img_dir,"font.ttf"))
def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_name , 25)
    font_game = pygame.font.Font(font, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
```

вот ошибка:

```
File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\готовый Shmup\Space(Finale).py", line 34, in draw_text
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_name , 25)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: not a file object
```

в других способах тоже были ошибки,если что, уточню

Comment: так у вас в `font_name` уже шрифт находится, зачем его еще куда-то совать?

Comment: руки растут из одного места,забил на проблему,но спасибо

Comment: После запятых, кстати, всегда пишутся пробелы. Запомните это на будущее, и людям будет приятнее читать ваши вопросы.